# Accessing an array while iterating over it mutably

Tags: rust

*Disclaimer*: I am fairly new to Rust.

## Simplified Use-Case

From the best practices I read about Rust so far, I understood that iterating with `for elem in array {}` is preferred over to `for i in 0..array.len(){}`.

Is there any way to iterate over an array mutably, while simultaneously accessing specific elements from it by index?

My usecase is quite complex, so I wrote a simple fibonacci calculator to demonstrate the problem:

```rust
let mut arr = vec![0;10];
    
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 1;
    
for (i, elem) in arr.iter_mut().skip(2).enumerate() {
    *elem = arr[i-2] + arr[i-1];
}
   
println!("{:?}", arr);
```

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `arr` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Of course this makes sense, but is there a way around that? I mean, from a programmers perspective, it is obvious that this code is safe, because we borrow immutable from an array that we already have in the current context as mutable, just not directly, but through an iterator.

Of course, if I implement it by iterating over the indices, it works:

```
let mut arr = vec![0;10];
    
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 1;
    
for i in 2..arr.len(){
    arr[i] = arr[i-2] + arr[i-1];
}
    
println!("{:?}", arr);
```

> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]

So, my question, is there another way to solve this problem, or do I have to use the second version?

---

## Real use-case

This code is to demonstrate my use-case and does not do anything on its own.

```
let mut labels = vec![vec![0; width]; height];

for (y, row) in labels.iter_mut().enumerate() {
    for (x, label) in row.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        let label_left = {
            if x > 0 && some_condition() {
                Some(labels[y][x - 1]) // <== Fails
            } else {
                None
            }
        };

        let label_top = {
            if y > 0 && some_condition() {
                Some(labels[y - 1][x]) // <== Fails
            } else {
                None
            }
        };

        *label = some_function(label_left, label_right);
    }
}
```

Rewriting this with a 2D-index based iteration feels a lot like I'm trying to force C programming style into Rust, so I can't believe it's the intended way.

Comment: Do not forget about `unsafe`. Such issues are what it is usually used for.

Comment: I kind of disagree ... I'd rather use safe rust as much as possible. IMO unsafe rust is for communication with external libraries and for performance optimization on cache level.

Comment: I don't know why you want to avoid using indices. `arr[i] = arr[i-2] + arr[i-1]` seems more clear to me than `*elem = arr[i-2] + arr[i-1]` even before you get into the `iter_mut().skip(2).enumerate()` bit. You're accessing multiple elements at once -- that's fundamentally a violation of the `Iterator` contract, which only gives you one thing at once.

Answer (score 1):

A more 'functional' way to implement your simplified use-case could be:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut arr = vec![0; 10];

    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 1;

    let arr: Vec<i32> = arr
        .iter()
        .skip(2)
        .scan((arr[0], arr[1]), |pair, _| {
            let (a, b) = *pair;
            let c = a + b;
            *pair = (b, c);

            Some(c)
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", arr);
}
```

But this is not necessarily more rusty or easier to read than iterating with index. That said, if you are willing to go down the FP rabbit hole, it can be very rewarding.

Comment: While this might work in 1D, i don't see an easy way of transferring it to 2D, as my real use-case will be :/ I am a big fan of functional programming, though, I wish this would work as a solution

Comment: With the power of functional holy trinity: map, filter and fold, you can do anything to a collection. Take your time and you'll get there.